# Firefox form field stealing focus when another field is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, firefox

I'm having an issue with a form in firefox with multiple text input fields. When I click on a second or third input, the first text input steals focus. This happens unless I highlight something in one of the other fields (in which case it retains focus).

Has anyone ever run into this issue before?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPrPYm

```
  <div>
    <form action="/forms/SaveResponse" id="qansform" method="post">
      <input id="NavigationType" name="NavigationType" type="hidden" value="Update" />


      <div>
        <div class="question input-select">
          <label>
            <span class="label">Name:</span>
            <input data-rule-maxlength="500" data-rule-required="true" id="FirstTextBox" name="FirstTextBox" type="text" value="" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <span class="label">Contact:</span>
            <input data-rule-maxlength="500" data-rule-required="true" id="SecondTextBox" name="SecondTextBox" type="text" value="" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <span class="label">Phone Number:</span>
            <input data-rule-maxlength="20" data-rule-required="true" id="ThirdTextBox" name="ThirdTextBox" type="text" value="" />
            <br />
            <br />
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="question input-select">
          <label>
            <span class="label">Date:</span>
            <input class="datefield" data-rule-date="true" data-rule-required="true" id="FourthTextBox" name="FourthTextBox" type="text" value="" />
            <br />
            <br />
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="button" value="Go Back" class="cancel form-submit" onclick="cancelClick()" />

    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a https://jsfiddle.net/ with an example?

Comment: Added codepen (jsfiddle is being weird for me right now - won't save fiddles!)

Comment: I tested in firefox and could not reproduce.

Comment: It is because  you put whole span and input in single label tag. Which is wrong. Check Working: http://jsfiddle.net/3n5xbk7p/  not working: http://jsfiddle.net/3n5xbk7p/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you were using `<label>` tags wrongly. Here's an example of how to do it:

```html
<label for="FirstTextBox">
  <span class="label">Name:</span>
</label>
<input data-rule-maxlength="500" data-rule-required="true" id="FirstTextBox" name="FirstTextBox" type="text" value="" />
```

And here is your example fixed http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqrqYd

Comment: You are totally right. One of my developers handed this problem to me and I completely missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Knowing this, it's interesting that Chrome didn't seem to have any issue with it.

Comment: Yes, since a label with a contained input field is also a valid syntax, my guess is that chrome threats the priority stack in a different order, the focus event from the input field may have a higher priority then the focus event from the label. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqrqYd